# Java synchronizing a method in a class

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, synchronized

Basically my hierarchy is I have a class A which starts 100 threads of class B, and class B uses a class called `FileCreator`. `FileCreator` class has a method called `writeToFile()` which is synchronized.
This is how I instantiate it within class B:

```
FileCreator newFile = new FileCreator(downloadFolder, content, page.getWebURL());
newFile.writeToFile();
```

Now my issue is `writeToFile()` is not actually synchronized. Basically this is what I have done to my `writeToFile()`

```
public synchronized void writeToFile() {
        System.out.println("Thread accessed");
        //Some stuff here
        System.out.println("Thread FINISHED!");
}
```

However I am getting this result in my console:

```
Thread accessed
Thread accessed
Thread FINISHED!
Thread FINISHED!
```

So it's not really synchronized. Because these classes are accessed by different threads I am assuming that causes the problem. Is there a way to actually synchronize my method so that there would be only one access at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use "dummy" Object and synchronize on it. **The block level is more efficient because it does not lock the whole method.**

```
Object xLock = new Object(); // !!! in you main thread

....

public void writeToFile() {
    synchronized(xLock ){
      System.out.println("Thread accessed");
      //Some stuff here
      System.out.println("Thread FINISHED!");
    }       
}
```

But sure you can write as well:

```
 public void writeToFile() {
    synchronized(this){
      System.out.println("Thread accessed");
      //Some stuff here
      System.out.println("Thread FINISHED!");
    }       
  }
```

}

Bear in mind that `xLock` should be initiated in main Thread.

**As reference**

**======================**

*Method Level*

```
class MethodLevel {

  //shared among threads
SharedResource x, y ;

public void synchronized method1() {
   //multiple threads can't access
}
public void synchronized method2() {
  //multiple threads can't access
}

 public void method3() {
  //not synchronized
  //multiple threads can access
 }
}
```

*Block Level*

```
class BlockLevel {
  //shared among threads
  SharedResource x, y ;

  //dummy objects for locking
  Object xLock = new Object();
  Object yLock = new Object();

    public void method1() {
     synchronized(xLock){
    //access x here. thread safe
    }

    //do something here but don't use SharedResource x, y
    // because will not be thread-safe
     synchronized(xLock) {
       synchronized(yLock) {
      //access x,y here. thread safe
      }
     }

     //do something here but don't use SharedResource x, y
     //because will not be thread-safe
    }//end of method1
 }
```

Comment: see my edit, only what is inside `synchronized(xLock ){/*..*/}`

Comment: Yes, I just understood. So I should be creating a singleton xLock?

Comment: yes, just create single `Object` like `Object lock = new Object()` and use above mentioned approach.

Comment: Did you create `Object xLock = new Object();` in main class `A`?

Comment: OK i just fixed it sorry it was my singleton issue :)

Comment: No I did not do that I did it in `FileCreator` by using block = ThreadBlock.getInstance();

Answer (score 1):

It is synchronized on a per instance basis. `synchronized` on an instance method means

```
synchronized(this) {
    ...
}
```

but since you have 100 instances, none of them blocks. You'll need to synchronized on a shared object. Either pass a `lock` object to each of the instances or only create one instance you pass to each `Thread`. `synchronize` on that instance.